# how to stretch an image in android

Tags: android, image, imageview, stretch

i have an image and i want to stretch it according to the screen size.
thats my code:

```
 <ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:baselineAlignBottom="false"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:maxWidth="@dimen/padding_small"
    android:src="@drawable/footerheader_bg" />
```

what happens is that the imageView frame is indeed stretched from side to side of the screen, but the image inside it remains as small as it was.
the image is a JPEG and im using a mac (if thats relevant).
Thanks!

Comment: what about you aspect ratio? Does it fit with both width/height set to fill_parent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you do not mind what happens to the aspect ratio then you can use one of the 2 ways

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_content"
android:src="@drawable/footerheader_bg"
android:scaleType="fitXY"
```

or

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_content"
android:background="@drawable/footerheader_bg"
```

However if aspect matters, then try this

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_content"
android:src="@drawable/footerheader_bg"
android:scaleType="fitCenter"
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this `android:src="@drawable/footerheader_bg"`

to

```
android:background="@drawable/footerheader_bg"
```

and

```
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

Answer (score 1):

You have two choices:

**1)**
Keep the

`android:src="@drawable/footerheader_bg"` propertie and add the propertie `android:scaleType="fitXY"`

**2)**
Delete the  `android:src="@drawable/footerheader_bg"` propertie and use 
use the background properties `android:background="@drawable/footerheader_bg"`, your image will stretch by default, don' forget to set:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_content"
```